# What resources explain Reflection and Meta Programming in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, metaprogramming

I've been programming in C# for a while now and would say I can use it and the .Net library fairly well. One huge gap in my knowledge though is how to use Reflection and Meta Programming with .Net/C#.

Can someone point me to some good resources on the subject and how to get started with it?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/?Query=reflection

Comment: @John am I the only one that thinks MSDN is some of the most difficult documentation to follow?

Comment: i hope you'll take the time to tell the MSDN folks what issues you have with their documentation. There's a "feedback" link at the bottom of each page.

Answer (score 1):

To understand Reflection, you really need to understand the CLR. There is an excellent book called [CLR via C#](http://tinyurl.com/3alejm9), which teaches CLR concepts using C#.